# Android ArrayAdapter Crashes when I want to load listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

**Target**

I am trying to create a shopping list in Android. This has one activity class (MainActivity.java) and one layout (activity_main.xml)
This program has an edittext for adding items and a listview for the shopping list items.

I use genymotion to run mt program on. When I run this program, it crashes totally.

**Structure**

My layout activity_main.xml class:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newItemText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/addItemHint"
        android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the OnCreate method in my MainActivity class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Inflating the view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //References from the UI widgets
        ListView shoppingListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shoppingListView);
        final EditText newShoppingItemText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newItemText);

        //the list of shopping items
        final ArrayList<String> shoppingListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        shoppingListItems.add("Eggs");
        shoppingListItems.add("Bacon");
        //the array adapter, which binds the shopping list items array to the listview
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main,shoppingListItems);

        //Bind the adapter to the listview
        shoppingListView.setAdapter(aa);

        newShoppingItemText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    if( (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) ) {
                        shoppingListItems.add(0, newShoppingItemText.getText().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        newShoppingItemText.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                        return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Problem**

When I run this code in Genymotion I get following error output in my logcat:

> Process: com.example.jonas.shoppinglist, PID: 8354
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
>               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in this line of your code

```
aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main,shoppingListItems);
```

You cant pass layout of yout activity as layout of single item in listview. Try this instead:

`aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,shoppingListItems);`

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect:

`aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_main,shoppingListItems);`

The constructor you are calling is:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29

And you are passing it the activity layout, where you should be passing it a layout for specific items in the list.